# gdbserver can't intrrupt "SOME" process,kill(pid,2) called by gdbserver didn't send SIGINT to process,what's happening?

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, gdbserver

Envirment is:

target:x86_64 client,runs the program which is striped

Host:x86_64 server ,has code,toolchain,striped program,symbles file for debug

run gdbserver on target:

> %gdbserver --multi :1234  /pathtolog/gdb.log

run program on target:

> ./someprogram &
>
> [1] PID

run gdb on host:

> %gdb
>
> (gdb)target extended-remote TARGETIP:1234
>
> (gdb)file someprogram
>
> (gdb)setrootfs pathtorootfs
>
> (gdb)...//set lib path etc.
>
> (gdb)attach PID
>
> ...//load everything as normal
>
> ...//stop somewhere
>
> (gdb)c
>
> ^C^CThe target is not responding to interrupt requests.
>
> Stop debugging it? (y or n)

tried to find the root cause:

on the target:

gdb attach to gdbserver(yes I can use gdb on the target right now,but the target machine shall be released without gdb,symbles,etc. for size).

> (gdb) b kill
>
> Breakpoint 1 at 0xf760afb0
>
> (gdb) c
>
> Continuing.

when press ctrl+c from host gdb ,gdbserver will break into the breakpoint

> Breakpoint 1, 0xf760afb0 in kill () from /lib/libc.so.6
>
> (gdb)

I'v checked register,the %esp register shows like this:

> (gdb) x /32wx 0xffee8070
>
> 0xffee8070:     0xfffffe0c      0x00000002      0x00000001      0x00000000

0xfffffe0c = -PID
0x00000002 = SIGINT

some program will get the signalwhen gdbserver continue .
so，kill() is good for "SOME PROGRAM",not all.

And I'v use tcpdump monitored data between gdb/gdbserver.
If kill() worked （for "GOOD" program),gdbserver will send a packet to gdb.

I'v tried [sigmonitor](https://github.com/honkiko/signal-monitor),found out gdbserver didn't send any sigal to "BAD program" in this case.but I can call kill(pid,2) int gdbserver debuging gdb process

> (gdb) call kill(PID,2)

then dmesg shows like this

> [11902.060722] ==========send_signal===========
>
> ```
>           SIG 2 to 6141[a.out], tgid=6141
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
>           SIG 19 to 6142[a.out], tgid=6141
> ```
>
> [11902.111135] Task Tree of 6142 = {
>
> ...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out a possible match [bug of gdbserver](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=18945).
parameter of kill() called by gdbserver is -PID,not PID.

> gdbserver sends SIGINT not to the process, but to the process group (-signal_pid).
>   But the attached process is not always a process group leader. 
>   If not, "kill (-signal_pid, SIGINT)" returns error and fails to interrupt the attached process.

```
static void linux_request_interrupt (void)
{
  /* Send a SIGINT to the process group.  This acts just like the user
     typed a ^C on the controlling terminal.  */
-  kill (-signal_pid, SIGINT);
+  kill (signal_pid, SIGINT);
}
```

This problem remained in gdb-8.1,don't know why they don't think it's a problem.